# Object not posting correctly with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, object, post

I have a simple function that compiles values and ids of multiple inputs into an object, then passes them to an AJAX function.  Unfortunately, I cannot get the data to post correctly.  The processing page is definitely called and the variables make it to the js (the object looks correct in the console), but all the variables seem to be blank on the processing page.

scripts:

```
$("#" + buttonId).find(".submitValue").each(function() {
    inputId = $(this).attr("id").replace(buttonId + "-", "");
    inputValue = $(this).val();

    var data = {}; 
    data[inputId] = inputValue;
    dataObject.push(data);
});

$.post(
    'ajax/' + buttonId + '.php', 
    {
        'nextForm': formNumber,
        dataObject: dataObject
    },
    function (response) {
        $("#" + buttonId).append(response);

    }
);
```

relevant php processing page (there are many more variables than this, but it all looks the same - the ids in this example are "timeBlockLocation", "appointmentAddress1", "appointmentAddress2") - connection has been created

```
$nextForm = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["nextForm"]);
$timeBlockLocation = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["timeBlockLocation"]);
$appointmentAddress1 = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["appointmentAddress1"]);
$appointmentAddress2 = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["appointmentAddress2"]);
```

Here is the var_dump on the processing page for $_POST:

```
array(2) {
  ["nextForm"]=&gt;
  string(1) "6"
  ["dataObject"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(1) {
      ["timeBlockLocation"]=&gt;
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    array(1) {
      ["appointmentAddress1"]=&gt;
      string(4) "TEST"
    }
    [2]=&gt;
    array(1) {
      ["appointmentAddress1"]=&gt;
      string(5) "TEST2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should be using `$_POST["dataObject"]["timeBlockLocation"]`, `$_POST["dataObject"]["timeBlockLocation"]`, etc. Do a `var_dump($_POST)` to quickly see what's going on otherwise.

Comment: I updated the post with the var_dump.  As you can see, I use this function with multiple processing pages, so the inputs are not always consistent.  It is a little hard to predict their order and specify an array number on the processing page.

Comment: I ended up successful using: $timeBlockLocation = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["dataObject"][0]["timeBlockLocation"]);  I would love to get rid of the extra parameter if possible.  Otherwise, this led me to the answer.  I can mark you correct if you create an anwer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was navigating the arrays wrong, as Mahn pointed out.  I ended up being successful using the notation like:

```
$timeBlockLocation = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["dataObject"][0]["timeBlockLocation"]);
```